# Specify a special cpu for a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu

I have 2 threads. I want to tell one of them to run on first cpu and the second one on the second cpu for example in a machine with two cpu. how can I do that?

this is my code

```
UCI UCIMain = new UCI();
Thread UCIThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UCIMain.main));
UCIThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
UCIThread.Start();
```

and for sure the class `UCI` has a member function named `main`. I want to set this thread in 1st processor for example

Comment: What is the reason for caring? (..not trying to be sarcastic)

Comment: There are tools like the Task Parallel Library to optimize these concerns for us - why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It's probably best just to let the OS decide that.

Comment: Keep in mind that to do this, you will need to know how many CPU the user have. This may not be common, but the user of your application MAY still use one of them older CPU that have only 1 core (or older mobile single-core CPU)

Comment: yes. I will check how many cpu is available in one's computer before doing that.

Comment: the problem is my program only use 50% of the cpu. it is obvious it only uses one processor

Comment: @SanJacinto: I want to use all processors of a computer. but now it just uses one of my processors.

Comment: @DaveZych : as it seems the os just use one cpu.

Comment: _it is obvious it only uses one processor_ - then it is obvious that it only _can_ use 1 CPU for some other reason. You are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @casperOne. I'm not sure there was any need to delete my answer!

Comment: @Nick : Link-only answers are discouraged. You can still edit it but it was the wrong direction anyway.

Comment: If the usage is 50% CPU, then I'm betting that Henk is 100% right - only one thread is running.  If both threads were ready all the time, the OS would surely run one on each core.

Comment: It is here in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't recommend this, but if you really need to: it is possible by tapping into the native Win32 system calls, specifically `SetThreadAffinityMask`. You will need to do some `DllImport`s:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);
```

And then use the them inside each spawned thread (with a different parameter for the mask, of course):

```
// set affinity of current thread to the given cpuID
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), new IntPtr(1)); // CPU 0
```

Answer (score 2):

On .NET, you have [ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx) and [ProcessThread.IdealProcessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.idealprocessor)

But since you are talking about a `Thread` and not `Process`, I believe there is no directly available way of doing this in .NET.

There is `Thread.SetProcessorAffinity()` but it's only available for XNA on Xbox.

Comment: see my edit, there is not an out-of-the-box solution for Threads.

Comment: Yeah - you might want to edit this answer since my answer was deleted by @casperOne - a supposed moderator...!

Comment: thanks! just did. if yours was deleted mine should've been too :P

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. OS task scheduler is much more clever than manual tweaks. You can technically use [thread affinity](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a55733db-cac0-4ccb-a3cc-a584742b41f9/), but it's not usually a good idea. Instead use thread pool or TPL library.

If one core is super busy and another one is not. Then one thread will be starving for processing power, whereas another core will not be loaded at all.

Comment: the problem is my program only use 50% of the cpu. it is obvious it only uses one processor

Comment: Can you describe what these two threads do? Can you post some simplified code? Are they doing any IO?